# Need Ionic Barcode Scanner constatly to Scan

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode, barcode-scanner, ngcordova

I am trying to create an hybrid app with Ionic that uses the barcode-scanner plugin.

The barcode-scanner itself is working fine. I can press a button and the camera view shows up and I can read a barcode.

But I need my own view with the the camera constantly checking if it sees any barcodes and to react to them.

In my example I need to quickly scan user cards and show details of the user.
The workflow should be as fast as possible. That is why I want to skip the step of pressing a button to open up the barcode scanner itself.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: When I had looked into this previously, there didn't seem to be an out-of-the-box way of doing this.  You would need to make some adjustments to the plugin.  If I'm wrong or if anything has changed, I would also love to know the answer.